# Accessing defrost vents (removing dash?) on 2010 Wrangler Rubicon 2-door w/o power windows

Tags: dashboard, wrangler

Per the title, I have a 2010 Wrangler Rubicon 2-door without power windows. My daughter accidentally dropped an important bolt into the defroster vents between dash and windshield on the passenger side.

I figure I need to remove some of the dash to get at this vent. However, the videos I've found online are for models that have power windows, with window controls between the two center vents, and start by [removing the window controls](https://youtu.be/ZeadDcIxNzY?t=46) and [accessing a bolt behind it](https://youtu.be/SKlU4ZtaarE?t=115).

I have no power windows/locks/alarm. My dash is completely smooth and unbroken between the center vents. (It's not like there's a blank insert in place, they used a different piece of molded plastic for the dash.)

[image: photo of the center dash, showing smooth plastic between and around the main air vents]

Assuming that I need to remove the dash, what do I need to do to get it off for this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have lots of general experience in this arena, but not particular experience on that particular Jeep instrument panel.

1. Lets address that finish panel around the radio. My guess is that screw is common to power window equipped unit and not. To get to that screw, you will have to remove the round vent registers.  Check out [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VtzrNJVTPl4)  Note, that video is for the 2011 Model Year (MY) Instrument Panel, and your is a 2010 MY... but my guess is they are going to be very similar. I will say, most manufacturers tend to have tabs and slot, or metal snap retainers and minimal screw mounts for those trim panels.  At any rate, once the panel registers are removed you can use a 1/4" ratchet to remove any screw attachments inside.
2. With that said, your focus seems to be on the defroster grill and removing the bolt.  There are two types of defroster grills in use... One is a built into the instrument panel cover. The only way to get inside the defroster duct is to remove the instrument panel.
3. The other type of defroster grill is a snap on cover.  The cover snaps on from the top.  This is a good news, bad news kind of thing. Yes, its easy to replace the defroster grill cover by simply snapping it into position. The bad news is there is zero, zip, no chance of removing a 10 year old defroster grill without damage.  That part gets a heck of a lot of sunshine, and the UV rays and ten years of aging will make that extremely brittle.
4. Getting the grill off is only half the battle.  You still will need to fish for the dropped bolt. Its possible that a magnet on a stick or gripper extension will help, but my guess the bolt will migrate down into the Heating Ventalitation Air Conditioning (HVAC) air ducting system. The only way to get there is to remove the entire instrument panel.
5. You are not actually going to remove the instrument panel, but instead you are going to pull the instrument panel car rearward 12 inches or so, than roll it face down on a heavily padded center hump. To do this, you will need to drop the steering column, remove the center console, remove the transmission shift handle.  You will need to disconnect lots of wiring connectors. I'm nearly positive on that vehicle the defroster nozzle is bolted to the bottom of the instrument panel hard plastic substrate, so when you roll the instrument panel back you should be able to get to the bolt.
6. Its not clear on your do-it-yourself-auto-mechanic experience.  This is a big job, and although not particularly difficult, there are pieces that will cause you huge headaches. Hint, disconnection electrical connectors with lots of wires is never easy. If this is your first time doing this job, take lots and lots of photos so you can remember where everything goes. This job will take LOTS of patience. My guess you should plan on giving yourself 8 to 10 hours for the job. And I will say the job goes way better if you have an assistant.
7. And in the rare case the bolt has really fallen deep inside the HVAC ductwork, you may have to remove the HVAC plenum. And that is a huge job. You have to evacuate/recover the refrigerant system, and drain the engine coolant. Disconnect the heater hoses and A/C hoses on the engine side of the dash panel. Ugh.  No fun. I will say, with care (and a bit of luck) this step won't be necessary.

Are you sure, really sure you can't move on without that dropped bolt? I seriously doubt it will do much damage, besides creating an annoying rattle.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Your experience and time estimate puts it out my comfort zone. I am certain you are correct about UV exposure making plastic snaps brittle, and it seems very likely now that I will only break things in a way that leaves more unsatisfying rattles instead of fixing. Fishing with a magnet and line, though, does sound like an intriguing and far easier way to MAYBE get the bolt back, and failing that I'll just buy a replacement bolt (for the mirrors). Though I have not tried your advice, and it does not directly answer the question, I'm giving you the accept. :)